# In a WordPress Gutenberg block how to set Post attributes (e.g. slug/category) programmatically in JavaScript?

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a block which saves user input to a custom meta field - in Gutenberg. I also want to be able to set the Post attributes for the Post which contains the block, programmatically, in my block. (In JS). For example; I want to be able to add a term (Category or custom taxonomy) to the post via code in the block.

I appreciate that this means that one block is editing the Post content and I am not sure this is part of the model? (Though you can edit the post metadata).

I have looked at the methods in core/editor and I don't see anything there about setting values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useDispatch()` hook with the `editEntityRecord()` function to modify post attributes in your `edit` function.

First, import it:

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
```

Then set up the pieces you'll need in your `edit` function:

```js
const { editEntityRecord } = useDispatch('core');

const {
    postType,
    postId,
} = useSelect((select) => {
    const {
        getCurrentPostType,
        getCurrentPostId,
    } = select('core/editor');

    return {
        postType: getCurrentPostType(),
        postId: getCurrentPostId(),
    };
}, []);
```

Then, wherever you want to change an attribute (e.g. an `onChange`):

```js
editEntityRecord('postType', postType, postId, {
    slug: 'your-new-slug',
});
```

Comment: I get the error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. How other ways can I reference `@wordpress/data`